# how does one use the current value of a foreign key during an insert using sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I've got two tables. one holds common data for the other and is referenced via a foreign key.

```
create table metric(name text, metric_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT);
create table metric_value( name text, val text, metric_id integer, foreign key (metric_id) references metric(metric_id) );
```

I add data like this:

```
INSERT INTO metric(name) VALUES( 'loopcnt');
INSERT INTO metric_value( name, val, metric_id) VALUES ( 'tst1', '0.01', 1);
INSERT INTO metric_value( name, val, metric_id) VALUES ( 'tst2', '0.41', 1);

INSERT INTO metric(name) VALUES( 'timed');
INSERT INTO metric_value( name, val, metric_id) VALUES ( 'tst1', '0.71', 2);
INSERT INTO metric_value( name, val, metric_id) VALUES ( 'tst2', '0.46', 2);
```

I'd rather not have the metric_id in the insert . Is there a way to grab the ID from the current value in the metric table and used that instead.

Comment: You basically just want the maximum value in the `metric.metric_id` column?

Comment: If you know the name of the item you're inserting data for, use a scalar subquery, something like `INSERT INTO metric_value(name,val,metric_id) VALUES ('test1', '0.01', (SELECT metric_id FROM metric WHERE name = 'loopcnt'));`

Comment: @mypetlion yes, I want the maximum value.

Comment: @shawn that might work. I'll try that tomorrow at work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the `metric_id` of the last inserted record in the `metric` table, and you know that that column is an `AUTOINCREMENT`, then you can safely assume that the one you want will be the record with the maximum value in the `metric_id` column. `INSERT` statements can take a `SELECT` statement for single values, so try this:

```
INSERT INTO metric(name) VALUES( 'loopcnt');
INSERT INTO metric_value( name, val, metric_id) VALUES ( 'tst1', '0.01', (SELECT MAX(metric_id) FROM metric));
INSERT INTO metric_value( name, val, metric_id) VALUES ( 'tst2', '0.41', (SELECT MAX(metric_id) FROM metric));

INSERT INTO metric(name) VALUES( 'timed');
INSERT INTO metric_value( name, val, metric_id) VALUES ( 'tst1', '0.71', (SELECT MAX(metric_id) FROM metric));
INSERT INTO metric_value( name, val, metric_id) VALUES ( 'tst2', '0.46', (SELECT MAX(metric_id) FROM metric));
```